# How To Open A Meeting Page Client Side

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'd like to open a SharePoint 2010 meeting page from a client side, Win form, C# application. How is this done? There is plenty of documentation to open a site and a List page but almost nothing on this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot open the page per se (unless you use a internet explorer wrapper). But you can get all the underlying data from that meeting (all data in sharepoint lives in lists) and render it in your winform page by rebuilding the page with winform layout, controls etc,

To extract the data you have a variety of options:

1. Client Object Model (check the item under building a console app) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094(v=office.14).aspx
2. Using Sharepoint Web services - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee705814(v=office.14).aspx
3. Using the REST API - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx

In your particular scenario I would go with the first option since it provides a more streamlined api for .net apps and allows among other goodies batching of commands which will improve the performance of your comms with the sharepoint server.

Comment: Thanks! To press my luck, the examples shows a page directly off the main site page. How can I open a page nested below that, such as an .aspx page, or something like "...default.aspx?InstanceID=20131205&Paged=Next&p_StartTimeUTC=2...:

Comment: Not sure if you understand my answer, the pages do not matter what metters is the item on the list that is supplying the content for the page. I would say look at that Instance Id and check all items in your meetings table

Comment: Maybe I'm not really understanding, yes. Could you provide a code example?